# Matching a URL in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:/.)$ result.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:/.)/$ result.php?u=$1
```

And what i'm trying to do is, rewrite http://example.com/http://google.com to http://example.com/result.php?u=http://google.com but I just get a "The requested URL was not found on this server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9:/\.]+)$ http://example.com/result.php?u=$1
```